# Implementing a linked list with a stack in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

For a prelab (meaning it's not for a grade), I'm supposed to implement my first ever stack using linked lists. I wrote it adding only one thing to the stack just as practice, as to why it's so short. Anyway, I have no compile errors, besides it saying that "new" is uninitialized in my create_stack function. This is also where I'm getting a segmentation fault, as it's not printing out my first printf function. I am also guessing that the problem is bigger than just me initializing the stack, but this is my problem's start. Please go easy on me if it's something simple, as, like I said, it's my first time doing stacks, and thanks for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_{
    char data;
    struct node_ *next;
}node;

typedef struct stack_{
    unsigned int size;
    node* stack;
}stack;

stack* create_stack();
void push(stack* s, char val);
char top(stack* s);
void pop(stack*s);

int main(void) {

    char value, val;

    stack* new = create_stack();

    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &value);

    push(new, value);

    val = top(new);

    printf("%c\n", val);

    pop(new);

    return 0;
}

stack* create_stack(){ //initializes the stack

    stack* new;

    new->size = 0;
    new->stack = NULL;

    return new;

}

void push(stack* s, char val) {

    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //allocates 

    if ( temp == NULL ) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory\n");
    }

    else{
        temp->next = s->stack;
        temp->data = val;
        s->stack = temp;
        s->size = (s->size) + 1; //bumps the counter for how many elements are in the stack
    }

}

void pop(stack* s) {

    node* temp;

    temp = s->stack;
    s->stack = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    s->size = (s->size) - 1; //subtracts from counter

}

char top(stack* s) {

    node* temp = s->stack;

    char value = temp->data;

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it crashes is that you never allocate any memory when you create the stack. Do `stack* new = malloc (sizeof(stack));` in the create_stack function.

For the future you might want to use better variable names. Using for instance using `new` as the name for the stack isn't that good - it isn't very descriptive plus it's a reserved keyword in several languages, C++ for example.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I figured that it was something simple... it always is!

Answer (score 0):

`stack *new` creates a local pointer, but it has nothing to point to yet.  Since you want the stack to continue to exist after the function completes, you should allocate memory for it using malloc (and eventually free it using free).

So your create_stack function should start with:

```
stack* new = malloc(sizeof(stack));
```

An alternative would be to declare the stack as a local variable in your main function, and pass it as an argument into create_stack to initialize it:

```
stack new;
create_stack(&new);
```